# WiX Installer use RegistrySearch result for directory

Tags: wix

I'm trying to create an installer using WiX for an add-in to a product called SolidWorks.

Looking at the [docs](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/getting-started/where-to-install/) led me to believe that I should be able to look up a location based on a registry value to find the install destination.

Here is the registry value I'm trying to target:
[image: Registry picture]

As seen in the picture it is located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\SolidWorks\SOLIDWORKS 2022\Setup\SolidWorks Folder`.

I've tried to follow the instructions and have tried many iterations, with the following being the latest.

```xml
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" Name="SolidWorks Add-In" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="My Company" UpgradeCode="073e3b99-1977-4a3e-a4dc-0d61cc6ddbee">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Description="SolidWorks Add-In Installer" Manufacturer="My Company" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes"  CompressionLevel="high" />

        <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installer" Level="1">
            <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
        </Feature>

        <Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="v" />
        <Property Id="SOLIDWORKSDIR">
            <RegistrySearch Id="SolidWorksRegistry" Type="raw" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\SolidWorks\SOLIDWORKS 2022\Setup" Name="SolidWorks Folder" />
        </Property>
    </Product>

    <Fragment>

        <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
                <Directory Id="SOLIDWORKSDIR" Name=".">
                    <Directory Id="My_Company" Name="My Company">
                        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SolidWorks Add-In" />
                    </Directory>
                </Directory>
        </Directory>
    </Fragment>

    <Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
             <Component Id="AutofacLibrary" Guid="3124c97d-079d-48fe-bc7c-e594bf49ae4a">
                 <File Id="AutofacDLL" Name="Autofac.dll" DiskId="1" Source="..\SolidWorksAddIn\bin\Release\Autofac.dll" KeyPath="yes" />
                 <File Id="AutofacPDB" Name="Autofac.pdb" DiskId="1" Source="..\SolidWorksAddIn\bin\Release\Autofac.pdb" />
             </Component>
        </ComponentGroup>
    </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

This seems to completely ignore the registry value though and the install location is `C:\My Company\SolidWorks Add-In`

I can't figure out what needs to change. How am I targeting the registry value incorrectly or referencing the property incorrectly that isn't allowing the installer to place the installed files in the directory I want them to be in?

Comment: Is that a 64-bit registry key? Is your package 64-bit?

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments above, the issue is that the registry key is in the 64-bit hive but the package was 32-bit. The fix is to either make the package 64-bit (so the searches look in 64-bit locations by default) or make the registry search 64-bit by adding the `Win64='yes'` attribute.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! I see that you are the main person behind FireGiant. Are the docs on GitHub? I would be happy to create a PR to add some clarity around this. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out.